# No puedo resolver porque se duplica el resultado en Consola de ejercicio en Java

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente ejercicio realizado en Java, en el cual, no se porque, los valores en consola (cuando ejecuto la aplicación) se duplican.
Es un ejercicio de calculo de averiguar los números primos de 1 a 10000

```
public class NumerosPrimos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        CalculoPrimo numeroPrimo=new CalculoPrimo();

        for(int i=1;i<=10000;i++) { 

            int resultadoPrimos=numeroPrimo.esPrimo(i);

            System.out.println(resultadoPrimos);

        }

    }


}




class CalculoPrimo{

    int esPrimo=0;

    public int esPrimo(int numero) {

        if(numero%2!=0) {

            esPrimo=numero;
        }

        return esPrimo;

    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y poner una imagen o algo dde el resultado de lo que te arroja la consola? para tener algo mas visual de lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá está el código mejorado, ya que no mostrabas los primos sino los impares

```
public class NumerosPrimos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculoPrimo numeroPrimo=new CalculoPrimo();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            if(numeroPrimo.esPrimo(i)) System.out.println(i);
        }   
    } 
}
class CalculoPrimo{
    private int contador;
    private boolean primo;

    public boolean esPrimo(int numero){
        primo=true;
        contador=2;//Un nro. primo solo es divisible por sí mismo y por la unidad, por eso empezamos a partir del 2
                   //El cero también hay que excluirlo por que el cero como dividendo da siempre cociente cero

        //Va a salir del ciclo cuando primo sea falso(por que numero==1 o por que el módulo da 0) o contador
        //sea igual a numero(o sea que probó todos los divisores hasta llegar a numero)          
        while(primo && contador != numero){
            //El número 1 no es primo porque solo tiene un divisor, por lo tanto hay que excluirlo
            if(numero % contador == 0 || numero==1) primo=false;
            contador++;
        }
        return primo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Está un poco raro que haga el calculo una vez dentro del if, luego de nuevo para asignarlo a la variable que imprime. Con calcularlo una vez *antes* del if y validar sobre ese resultado, creo que bastaría

Comment: @Alfabravo Si, es verdad, es que solo me interesé en resolver el problema central que era que no duplique valores, además está mal el cálculo de números primos, ese es de números impares, ahora lo corrijo

Comment: @Alfabravo Ya lo edité

Comment: Excelente aporte!

Answer (score 0):

Este es tu error:

```
if(numero%2!=0)
```

Aca esta verificando el módulo de dicho numero solo para 2, cuando en realidad debes verificarlo para todos los números, puesto que un número primo es divisible solo para 1 y para si mismo.

aca una [guía](http://lineadecodigo.com/java/numeros-primos-en-java/) para que continues con tu proyecto

Answer (score -1):

después de darle el valor de (i) a resultadoPrimos este no cambiaba hasta que nuevamente encuentre un numero primo, por eso se debe de cambiar el valor esPrimo(i++);

```
        CalculoPrimo numeroPrimo=new CalculoPrimo();

    for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        int resultadoPrimos=numeroPrimo.esPrimo(i++);

        System.out.println(resultadoPrimos);
```